# rxjs - operator with both on-next and on-error callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I'm looking for the equivalent of `promise.then(onNextCallback,onErrorCallback)` in rxjs.

is there something like this?

- `pipe(concatMap(),catchError)` alternatives is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why are you not looking for `concatMap` and `catchError`? You can always nest them in a way that the error callback doesn't handle errors from the next callback. But yes, there doesn't appear to be a builtin function for this quite primitive operation.

Comment: can you give an example for: `You can always nest them in a way that the error callback doesn't handle errors from the next callback`? if you can do that, suggest to write it as in answer.

Comment: If don't know rxjs well enough to provide working code, but I mean something like `pipe(map(value => ({ok:true, value})), catchError(err => ({ok: false, value: err})), concatMap(({ok, value}) => ok ? handleSucess(value) : handleError(value)))`

Comment: yeah it can work. in real life, i would need to wrap the code in `map/concatMap` with try-catch to return the `{ok:boolean, value:T}` but i guess it is a valid solution. thanks. I guess that this is the only solution. personally, it looks like too much work for such a basic functionality.

Comment: Related Twitter thread: https://twitter.com/OliverJAsh/status/1291792172413530114

Comment: @cartant 1. i really appriciate that you took the time to link my question to some random thread in twitter. this is a great work on it's own. 2. it answered my question pretty good. thanks man

Comment: @Stav No worries, but it wasn't a random thread, for me. :) It was a question that Oliver asked me directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I also asked for this as well](https://twitter.com/OliverJAsh/status/1291792172413530114) and ended up writing my own.

```
import * as RxJS from 'rxjs';

/**
 * Like `promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)`. This is *not* the same as
 * `map(onNext).catchError(onError)`, because this operator will only catch errors resulting from
 * the original observable—not errors resulting from `onNext`.
 */
export const mapOrCatchError = <T, B>(
  onNext: (value: T) => B,
  onError: (value: unknown) => B,
): RxJS.OperatorFunction<T, B> => ob$ =>
  new RxJS.Observable<B>(observer =>
    ob$.subscribe({
      next: t => {
        let next: B;
        try {
          next = onNext(t);
        } catch (error) {
          observer.error(error);
          return;
        }
        observer.next(next);
      },
      error: error => {
        let next: B;
        try {
          next = onError(error);
        } catch (newError) {
          observer.error(newError);
          return;
        }
        observer.next(next);
        observer.complete();
      },
      complete: () => {
        observer.complete();
      },
    }),
  );
```

Tests:

```
import { marbles } from 'rxjs-marbles/jest';
import { mapOrCatchError } from '../operators';

describe('mapOrCatchError', () => {
  it(
    'should map',
    marbles(m => {
      const source$ = m.cold('--(a|)', { a: 1 });
      const expected = '      --(b|)';

      const actual$ = source$.pipe(
        mapOrCatchError(
          a => a + 1,
          _error => 0,
        ),
      );
      m.expect(actual$).toBeObservable(expected, { b: 2 });
    }),
  );
  it(
    'should catch',
    marbles(m => {
      const source$ = m.cold('--#');
      const expected = '      --(a|)';

      const actual$ = source$.pipe(
        mapOrCatchError(
          a => a + 1,
          _error => 0,
        ),
      );
      m.expect(actual$).toBeObservable(expected, { a: 0 });
    }),
  );
  it(
    'should error if error handler throws',
    marbles(m => {
      const source$ = m.cold('--#');
      const expected = '      --#';

      const error = new Error('foo');
      const actual$ = source$.pipe(
        mapOrCatchError(
          a => a + 1,
          _error => {
            throw error;
          },
        ),
      );
      m.expect(actual$).toBeObservable(expected, undefined, error);
    }),
  );
  it(
    'should not catch errors thrown by map function',
    marbles(m => {
      const source$ = m.cold('--(a|)');
      const expected = '      --#';

      const error = new Error('foo');
      const actual$ = source$.pipe(
        mapOrCatchError(
          () => {
            throw error;
          },
          _error => 'caught error',
        ),
      );
      m.expect(actual$).toBeObservable(expected, undefined, error);
    }),
  );
});
```

Comment: It could be a bit more advanced, e.g. the catch function should be able to return an `Observable` just like `catchError` does. For that, the implementation gets a bit more complicated, so I didn't bother. But if someone wants to take it a step further, be my guest :D

Comment: ho I thought that both callbacks support promises/observables haha. i missed that one :P  i will try to take it from here

Comment: maybe you can add in the title that both callbacks only support sync calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is not of my knowledge any operator that would do what you need.

What I do suggest, though, it's to create your own.

```
function promiseLike<T>(
  onNext: (data: T) => Observable<T>,
  onError: (err: any) => Observable<any>
) {

  type ErrorWrapper = {isError: boolean, err: any};
  const isErrorWrapper = (err: any): err is ErrorWrapper => {
    return err.isError && err.err !== undefined;
  }

  return function(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    return source.pipe(
      catchError((err) => of({isError: true, err})),
      switchMap((data) => isErrorWrapper(data) ? onError(data.err) : onNext(data))
    );
  }
}
```

The above basically wraps the error from source observable and then we `switchMap` to decide if I run the `onNext` and `onError`. This way, for sure, the `onError` won't catch possible errors coming from the `onNext`.

Here are the example of usage:

```
function getResolvingPromise(): Promise<string> {
  return Promise.resolve('SUCCESS');
}

function getErrorPromise(): Promise<string> {
  return Promise.reject('onError');
}

// Example with success
from(getResolvingPromise()).pipe(
  promiseLike(
    (data) => of(`received ${data}`),
    (err) => of(3)
  )
).subscribe((d) => console.log('Ex1', d)) // Logs Ex1 received SUCCESS

// Example with error
from(getErrorPromise()).pipe(
  promiseLike(
    (data) => of(`received ${data}`),
    (err) => of(3)
  )
).subscribe((d) => console.log('Ex2', d)) // Logs Ex2 3

// Example with internal error 2
from(getResolvingPromise()).pipe(
  promiseLike(
    (data) => throwError('Valid token not returned'),
    (err) => of(3)
  ),
  catchError(() => of('catching internal error'))
).subscribe((d) => console.log('Ex3', d)) // Logs Ex3 catching internal error
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

`source$` is the source Observable and you can provide corresponding functions via tap operator inside the `pipe`.

```
source$.pipe(
  tap({ next: onNextCallback, error: onErrorCallback })
)
```

Comment: I need to return observables from the `next` and `error` callbacks. thats why i'm looking for `promise.then` equivalent ;)

Comment: @StavAlfi Ah I see

Answer (score 0):

Is `.toPromise()` what are you looking for ?

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise

Then you can do your `.then(nextCallback)` `.catch(errorCallback)`

Comment: this was my workaround but it's a poor workaround because its working only if the observable is finite and im fine with waiting until the observable is done.